# How to stop Mysql auto converts data types on primary key during query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-performance

Say I have a simple an XXXX table, one column, an auto increment field

```
CREATE TABLE XXXXX (
     id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Table has 100M of records.

If I query with:

```
SELECT id FROM XXXXX WHERE id in (1, 2, 3);
```

All is good. However, if I do:

```
SELECT id FROM XXXXX WHERE id in (1, 2, 3, 'random value');
```

e.g. Using string instead of integers, as a result of some application bug..

I see the DB chucking on I/O, master/slave cluster getting seconds behind master, and queries being blocked for up to few minutes.

I assume there is some auto type conversion of all the huge index from int to string or something, but I might be wrong. Thoughts on what could be happening?

Comment: You might get more and better answers over at http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Even if it were possible to be done globally, that would break so many things for so many other queries, that you better not do it. And if you were to apply it just for this one instance, then, when you are actually putting manual effort to locally disable autoconversions, why not put the effort into catching the application bug instead.